# Form customization with file upload control along with excel sheet data row push

Tags: office-365

As part of Office 365 SharePoint site - Is this possible? (yes/no)

(1) A custom form having file upload control.

(2) On submission of data on custom form - the data should be pushed into excel file which is in document library.

(3) The uploaded file as part of form upload - should be uploaded to document library.

(4) The uploaded files in document library should be tagged into excel file.

Anyone can help please?

Comment: Question edited now. Please release it from "On Hold" status and make it active so that I can have response please.

Answer (score 1):

A SharePoint Document library can contain custom columns.  So you could upload a document, and then populate the extra columns.

You can by default [Export a document library to Excel](http://sharepointmaven.com/export-sharepoint-excel/).

So unless there is more to your request, it seems that all the requirements can be met with out-of-the-box SharePoint functionality, without introducing a need to write directly to an Excel file.